# Android game GPU compatibility issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

my first android game it's almost done, and I'm on the way to publish it on the play store.
Today I tested it on some friends phone and it worked on all except for a samung a5. On this phone the meshes flicker, apper and disapper and look deformed. This when playing game where I use a lot of frame buffer, in the main menu where there is a simpler animation everything look right.

The game is developed with libGdx and use some custom shader. I've tested it on 8 other different device without no issue (excepect for low frame rate on samsung galaxy tab s4).

I ask yours advise:

1) what should I start to check to find the problem with a5?

2) do you think I should delay the publication until the bug it's solved ora I should publish it excluding A5 ( or maybe all devices with similar GPU) from compatibility list?

My big problem is that at the moment I don't have the device with me (it's the personal phone of a friend of mine...) and probably I will have it for only a limited amount of time, so I want to be preparated to avoid to lock the device for too much time to my friend.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Just a clue: you can perhaps make more debugging and tries with developer settings, like disable GPU, etc. on the A5 device.

Comment: Thank you. My big problem is that at the moment I don't have the device with me (it's the personal phone of a friend of mine...) and probably I will have it for only a limited amount of time, so I want to be preparated to avoid to lock the device for too much time to my friend. I wil add it to the question to clarify better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, I'd make sure you don't have any OpenGL errors - add calls to glGetError and validate frame buffers and shader programs, you can do this without the device and adding extra asserts like this is always worthwhile (assuming you don't already have them). Next, try using the tools provided by the GPU manufacturer. In your case the [snapdragon profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-profiler). To minimize the time you'll be using your friends device, get the tools installed ahead of time and if you have access to another Qualcomm device, then use that to familiarize yourself with the software. With luck the cause of problem might become immediately obvious. If not, then it's just a binary search of disabling parts of your code until you narrow it down to a particular shader/draw call, then examine/tweak that to figure out what bit is going wrong.
2. That's a tough call. If it's a driver bug, then it might only occur on particular revisions. Some A5 devices might work if they're on different versions of Android from your friends device. That said, the A5 is relatively recent and Samsung/Qualcomm drivers tend to be pretty solid IME, so it's more likely an error in your code that happens to only be exposed on certain devices. Personally I would delay release unless your release strategy is timing sensitive, from the limited data you have, your game doesn't work on >10% of devices.